# Exporting old logs efficiently

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

As part of cloud migration effort, in order establish an archive of old logs, I'd like to export all existing logs from Stackdriver.

I know it is possible to export old logs via [`entries.list`](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list) as noted in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#general_problems):

> Use the entries.list API method to retrieve your older log entries and use the destination service's API to write the log entries to the export destination.

It appears that `gcloud logging read` relies on exactly this call, so I can pull all my logs via the following command:

```
gcloud logging read "logName=projects/my-project/logs/my-entity" --order asc | pv > production-my-entity.logs
```

However, this is **super slow**.

Is there a way to download older logs faster, like in bulk or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think at the moment there's no tools for your purpose, and this feature it's only available to store the logs in [Cloud Storage, BigQuery, or Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#before_you_begin). You can open a feature request in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_and_create_feature_requests_by_product):

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know Google has a tracker for feature requests. I've found an request to handle exactly this very situation https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64718059. I wasn't able to figure out how to "vote" though, so I starred the issue. Will mark your answer as final, thank you!

Comment: Staring the issue will subscribe you to it. You can mark that you are affected on the above section. I'm glad to help you!